# what is data.foo syntax in JSF/Rich Faces

Tags: ajax, jsf, richfaces

what is data.foo syntax in JSF/Rich Faces?

Say for example,

```
  <a4j:support event="onchange"  action="#{bean.retrieveStates}"  
  reRender="states_dropDown" data="#{student}"></a4j:support>
```

i am passing student object in data attribute. can I access in managed bean?
Documentation says this
 "Serialized (on default with JSON) data passed on the client by a developer on AJAX   request. It's accessible via "data.foo" syntax "

can some one please explain.

Comment: Note that "passing" is not passing *to* the Bean but retrieving *from*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this blogpost](http://shervinasgari.blogspot.com/2008/10/richfaces-32x-useful-tips.html):

> Another attribute is data, which allows you to get any additional data from
>   the server during an Ajax request. The data attribute can simply point to a
>   bean property via EL, and the data will be serialized in JSON format and
>   available on the client side. Here’s an example:

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Submit" reRender="out"
   data="#{bean.text}"
   oncomplete="alert(data)"/>
```

So yes - you can access any attribute of the managed bean and reference it (most often) in `oncomplete`.